# checkout remote branch of the pr

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

How can I go to the branch where other had pushed to pr? says the name is feature-fix, so what I did was

```
git remote add upstream <git_url>
git checkout -b upstream/feature-fix
```

I got
fatal: couldn't find remote ref feature-fix

Comment: If there is a branch named `feature-fix` in your remote, the correct command is simply : `git checkout feature-fix`. Is this the answer you were looking for ?

Comment: Just find the branch name and check it out like any outher branch. If the branch is from a foreign repository, you will need to get it from there.

Comment: Note too that after `git remote add`, before `git checkout`, you need to `git fetch` from the added remote. That is: `git remote add upstream <url> && git fetch upstream`, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a branch named `feature-fix` in your remote, the command that should work most of the time is simply :

```sh
git checkout feature-fix
```

If you need to be explicit about what remote should be targetted (say there already is a `feature-fix` branch in two remotes : `origin` and `upstream`) :

```sh
# 'git checkout -b' will create the new local branch
# 'git branch -u' will make that local branch track 'upstream/feature-fix'
git checkout -b feature-fix upstream/feature-fix
git branch -u upstream/feature-fix
```